# Artifactory LDAPS to Active Directory not working

Tags: ldap

Setting up a new JFROG Artifactory on a Windows server.
Trying to get LDAPS to work with Active Directory. When LDAP is set for port 389 the test user can authenticate, when I Chang it to LDAPS port 636 it fails.
I have the AD CA cert in the jfrog\artifactory\var\etc\security folder and also have it in the cacerts in the third-party\java\lib\security.
Testing LDAPS with ldp.exe passes\works.

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: we have a .local AD domain so the cert is from the AD CA.

Comment: the error i 2022-04-29T17:57:59.350Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [523b412e85f7473f] [o.a.s.l.AbstractLdapService:56] [http-nio-8081-exec-7] - Error connecting to the LDAP server.: mserver:636; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: mserver:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching mserver found.]

Comment: and 2022-04-29T18:15:52.521Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [cbd7de70bbcaed9 ] [o.a.s.l.AbstractLdapService:56] [http-nio-8081-exec-4] - Error connecting to the LDAP server.: mserver:636; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: mserver:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching mserver found.

Comment: Please provide the connection string and code you are using.